# HTML onerror does not work in Ionic / Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I have the following in an ionic page:

```
<ion-content>
   <video controls width="100%" (onerror)="playbackFailed()>
       <source src="https://emaple.com/wrong-video-url.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</ion-content>
```

And, in the typescript page component:

```
playbackFailed() {
   console.log('playback failed entered..');
}
```

`playbackFailed` function is never fired. I tried that with `onload` event as well and it is the same. However, it does work with `click` event. I am testing this with `ionic server` on Chrome.

Am I missing something here? Do I need to do anything special with Ionic / Angular to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ionic Video Player Plugin for playing videos inside Ionic App.
For Reference / and How to use it : 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-player/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why should I while html video works? And by the way, this Cordova plugin is only supported in/for Android.

Comment: I accept the support is only for Android. Well if you want it cross platform you can go with Video tag. look out for my Second Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enclosed your Video div with ion-content

Example :

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
  <video controls="controls" onerror="playbackFailed()" autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer">
   <source src="https://example.com/wrong-video-url.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Yes, it is already enclosed in `<ion-content>`. The code in my question was just a snippet.  I should change the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

In angular the callbacks should be defined as either :

> on-error="playbackFailed()"  or  (error)="playbackFailed()"

Comment: Did you try that? Is it working for you? I tried both and still not working!